# How to scroll into element provided in Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

> I need to scroll into element in puppeteer. How to achieve this ? And I tried to emulate mobile device to check for responsiveness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(selector).scrollIntoView());
```

Read more on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

You can also try:

```js
await page.hover(selector);
```

which under the hood it uses the same functionality.

Comment: @RajeshG added another method. both methods work with device emulation on my side. please add your code and provide more detail if it's not working.

Comment: @RajeshG Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.